# C# TCP listener not catching exception

Tags: c#, sockets, try-catch, tcplistener, networkstream

I have the following configuration for the server, that connects successfully to the client and runs the following threads.

My issue is when the client disconnects, it doesn't catch the exception:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   th_StartListen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListen));
   th_StartListen.Start();
   txtCmdOutput.Focus();
}

private void StartListen()
{
    //Creating a TCP Connection and listening to the port
    tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 6666);
    tcpListener.Start();
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Listening on port 6666 ...";
    int counter = 0;
    appStatus = 0;
 
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            counter++;
            clientList.Add(client);
            var ipend = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;

            //Updating status of connection
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected from " + ipend.Address.ToString();
            appStatus = 1;

            th_inPutStream = new Thread(() => outPutStream(client));
            th_inPutStream.Start();

            th_inPutStream = new Thread(() => inPutStream(client));
            th_inPutStream.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
             Cleanup();
        }
    }
}
```

It simply loops back and stops at `client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();` .

Would appreciate some ideas behind this.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it run Cleanup? Because what you describe sounds otherwise like it's exactly what it's supposed to do - loop back around and wait for a new client. What do you see when you debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at your logic. Since both input stream and output stream are running on separate threads, the code will continue executing after starting the  second thread, and when it does so, it will loop around, hit the true condition, and then start listening for a new client connection immediately.

Your exception isn't being caught because you're not generating an exception. A client closing it's connection to the server isn't necessarily an exception generating event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would you suggest I'd the best option to do so? Maybe with socket.poll?

Comment: Looking for the best way to check for an active connection with the client.

Comment: try to write to the connection.